# can't insert my data to database phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, registration

I got a problem in my code
I try to make a registration form using php
but I can't insert my data to database
this is my code

registration_form.php
     
     
     
     
     Registration Form

```
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="register.php">
 <table border="0">

 <tr><td>username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>

 <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>

 <tr><td>Confirm Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" /></td></tr>

 <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>

 </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

register.php

```
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 /* Now, we select the database */
 mysql_select_db("login&register");

 /* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $pass=$_POST['password'];
 /* we are now encrypting password while using md5() function */
 $password=md5($pass);
 $confirm_password=$_POST['confirm_password'];

 /* Now we will check if username is already in use or not */
 $queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$username' ");
 $checkuser=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);
 if($checkuser != 0)
 { echo "Sorry, ".$username." is already been taken."; }
 else {

 /* now we will check if password and confirm password matched */
 if($pass != $confirm_password)
 { echo "Password and confirm password fields were not matched"; }
 else {

 /* Now we will write a query to insert user details into database */
 $insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (username, password) VALUES ('$username',     '$password')");

 if($insert_user)
 { echo "Registration Succesfull"; }
 else
 { echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); }

 /* closing the if else statements */
 }}

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

when I click submit button the error message come out

```
 Object not found!

 The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

 Error 404

 localhost
 08/08/12 23:46:37
 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Please help me to solve this problem
thanks

Comment: Obligatory mention that your code is vulnerable to sql injection. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning that there are lots of frameworks available for PHP that takes all the pain out of adding authentication to your app.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I don't really get it actually...

Comment: Mansfield is saying that to use the code you've written will mean that anyone will be able to hack into your website, delete all your users information and worse.   Google SQL Injection Attack for more information.  I am suggesting that using a PHP framework like Yii (which offers a login system out of the box) will be a lot more reliable, stable and secure than anything you could write yourself.

Comment: I see...anw, my program is work already..thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
```

Your PHP file seems to be called `registration.php`

Comment: @BudiCzras - You're getting a 404 error, which means that the page you're trying to find isn't there. Are you sure both these are in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is `register.php` but your php file is called `registration.php`, change your form action to `registration.php`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `register.php` in your form instead of `registration.php`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a database issue.  Rather that register.php is not found.  You've saved the file as registration.php.

Comment: But the error you are getting is not a PHP error or a MySQL error that might look a bit like this - http://tranthelan.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/php-mysql-error.png - instead your webserver cannot find the target of the web form so it cannot reach the code you've written to handle the form.